# How work render action in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have method in controller like this:

```
  def create
    @player = Player.new(player_params)
    if @player.save
      flash[:success] = "Player created"
      redirect_to player_path(@player)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

And I have also test:

```
it "add players without nickname" do
  visit new_player_path
  click_button "Add player"
  current_path should eq new_player_path
end
```

But after call `render` method my current path is:

> http://localhost:3000/players

not

> http://localhost:3000/players/new

But the layout is from `players/new`. Why?
And what should be my test? In test I just want to check if user don't type in nickname in `nickname` filed application return to create user page (players/new path).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually when there is any errors then it moves from `new` to `create` action, so the path becomes http://localhost:3000/players, and the `render` just renders the new action's template here. Now the main question is why so?

As in the new action you have submitted the form with some data to the `create` action. Now if suppose it sends you back to `new` action then it would have to `redirect` you back to that page, so what will `redirect` do? It will make rails to loose all the form data which you have submitted and the data would never persist. So instead what is done is you remain on the `create` action which has the url: http://localhost:3000/players and it renders the `new` action which means the `new` action's template (or you can say form). It doesn't redirects it just renders it in the same one.

Now the question is how does the data persist? The data persists with the object. This line `@player = Player.new(player_params)` creates a new object of the `Player` class with the attributes you have passed in the form. Now as you remain in the same action and the object is persisted so the data on the form is also persisted.

If you want to test it then in your code replace this:

```
render 'new'
```

with:

```
redirect_to new_player_path
```

and you will notice the data would never persist unless you pass that explicitly.

Hope this helps.